# Vim what the :c command do?

Tags: keyword

On vim I enter for a mistake the

```
:c
```

And I can exit only with ctrl+c
What the command :c do?

Comment: Have you read `:help :c`? Thats a good first step any time you need to figure something out about vim

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate of the generic "how do I use Vim's help system"-question for now. Feel free to edit the question if you've still got a question after reading the help and we can reopen it.